# Combination of list elements

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have three 1d lists of different length and want to add all elements like this:

```
a = {1, 5};
b = {12, 15, 17};
c = {21, 23, 24, 28};

Flatten@Outer[{#1 + #2 + #3} &, a, b, c]
```

whereby results=$(a[[j]] + b[[k]] + c[[l]])|_{(j={1,2}; k={1,2,3}; l={1,2,3,4})}$

The expected result is:

```
{34, 36, 37, 41, 37, 39, 40, 44, 39, 41, 42, 46, 38, 40, 41, 
 45, 41, 43, 44, 48, 43, 45, 46, 50}
```

Could you show how the same result is obtained without using `Outer` but instead only with the slots `#1`, `#2`, `#3` and `Map`. Is that possible?

Comment: `#1 + #2 + #3 & @@@ Tuples[{a, b, c}]` or `Distribute[{a, b, c}, List, List, List, #1 + #2 + #3 &]` or with `Plus` instead of `#1 + #2 + #3 &`?

Comment: @kglr: Thank you ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have to use `Map` and `#1 + #2 + #3 &` literally:

```
Map[#1 + #2 + #3 & @@ # &, Tuples[{a, b, c}]]
```

> {34, 36, 37, 41, 37, 39, 40, 44, 39, 41, 42, 46, 38, 40, 41, 45, 41, \
>   43, 44, 48, 43, 45, 46, 50}

You get the same output with:

```
Map[Total, Tuples[{a, b, c}]]
Total[Tuples[{a, b, c}], {2}]
Flatten@Outer[Plus, a, b, c]
Plus @@@ Tuples[{a, b, c}]
Distribute[{a, b, c}, List, List, List, Plus]
```